# Knockout grabbing class from option

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to grab a class from an option within a select and then put that options class on the select Does this make any sense?

My goal is to try and color the select field so the user knows what color they are selecting.

My JSON looks like this

```
"Object": {
     "inputType": "select",
     "selectOptions": [{
       "value": "alert-success",
       "display": "Green",
       "class": "alert-success"
     }, {
       "value": "alert-info",
       "display": "Blue",
       "class": "alert-sinfo"
     }, {
       "value": "alert-warning",
       "display": "Yellow",
       "class": "alert-warning"
     }, {
       "value": "alert-danger",
       "display": "Red",
       "class": "alert-danger"
     }],
   },
```

And my html template looks like this:

```
<select data-bind="attr: { name : _name, disabled : $data.editable === false, class:$data.class }, options: selectOptions, optionsText: 'display', optionsValue: 'value', value: _value">
```

I have tried the above html with and without the $data. I have also tried using `optionsAfterRender`, but all that served to do was blow everything up.

Comment: Can you extend the code in your post into an [mcve]? A lot depends on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

There's few ways in which you could achieve this. With a bit less code if your class is the same as the name of the value:

```js
var DemoPage = (function() {
  function DemoPage() {
    var _this = this;
    var data = {
      inputType: "select",
      selectOptions: [{
        value: "alert-success",
        display: "Green"
      }, {
        value: "alert-info",
        display: "Blue"
      }, {
        value: "alert-warning",
        display: "Yellow"
      }, {
        value: "alert-danger",
        display: "Red"
      }]
    };
    _this._value = ko.observable();
    _this.selectOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
    _this.css = ko.computed(function() {
      //the logic for generating this class lies in a simple computed
      // if you want to use the class from the object, you could pass
      // the entire object as the value of select, and using ko.utils.arrayFirst
      // get the class. 

      // .. or if not, since your class and value is always the same:

      // create empty array that can hold many classes
      var classes = [];


      if (_this._value()) {
        // using this method you can add various classes based on multiple logic
        classes.push(_this._value());
      }

      // then just stringify and output directly to css binding
      return classes.join(' ');
    });
    _this.init = function() {
      _this.selectOptions(data.selectOptions)
    };

  }
  return DemoPage;
})();

var demoApp = new DemoPage();
ko.applyBindings(demoApp);
demoApp.init();
```

```css
.alert-info {
  background-color: blue;
}
.alert-success {
  background-color: green;
}
.alert-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
.alert-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.alert-danger,
.alert-info {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="css: css, options: selectOptions, optionsText: 'display', optionsValue: 'value', value: _value">
```

or if you really want to read the value directly inside select binding:

```js
var DemoPage = (function() {
  function DemoPage() {
    var _this = this;
    var data = {
      inputType: "select",
      selectOptions: [{
        value: "alert-success",
        display: "Green",
        cssClass: "alert-success"
      }, {
        value: "alert-info",
        display: "Blue",
        cssClass: "alert-info"
      }, {
        value: "alert-warning",
        display: "Yellow",
        cssClass: "alert-warning"
      }, {
        value: "alert-danger",
        display: "Red",
        cssClass: "alert-danger"
      }]
    };
    _this._value = ko.observable();
    _this.selectOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
    _this.selectedClass = ko.computed(function() {
      
      var selectedObject = ko.utils.arrayFirst(_this.selectOptions(), function(item) {
        return item.value === _this._value();
      }), classOutput;
      
      
      if (selectedObject) {
        classOutput = selectedObject.cssClass;
      } else {
        classOutput = '';
      }

      return classOutput;
    });
    _this.init = function() {
      _this.selectOptions(data.selectOptions)
    };

  }
  return DemoPage;
})();

var demoApp = new DemoPage();
ko.applyBindings(demoApp);
demoApp.init();
```

```css
.alert-info {
  background-color: blue;
}
.alert-success {
  background-color: green;
}
.alert-danger {
  background-color: red;
}
.alert-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.alert-danger,
.alert-info {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="attr: { class: selectedClass }, options: selectOptions, optionsText: 'display', optionsValue: 'value', value: _value">
```